# ggvis integrated into a function

Tags: r, ggvis

I am trying to create a basic function that you enter the currency and the function returns a ggvis linegraph, but an issue occurs due to the quotation marks

Current code:

```
ggcurr<-function(curr="AUD"){
    fx<-read.csv("rates.csv")
    fx$date<-as.character(fx$date)
    fx$date<-as.POSIXct(fx$date)
    gginput<-noquote(paste("~",curr,sep=""))

    fx%>%ggvis(~date,gginput)%>%
    layer_lines()
}
```

This code just returns a straight line.

I have also attempted as.name() to no avail

Many thanks!

**All solved**, the parse function worked, thank's for those who helped!

Comment: What do you mean by 'due to the quotation marks'? And what is in read.csv?

Comment: try `ggvis(~date,parse(text=paste("~",curr,sep="")))`

Comment: My apologies, 
The issue with quotation marks is that ggvis will not work if it's data%>%ggvis(~x,~"y") as oppposed to the correct form of data%>%ggvis(~x,~y)

The .csv is a garden varity df with cross rates for many currencies and the dates attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the solution you found with `parse`, this is the sort of thing that the `prop` function from **ggvis** can be used for.

For example, if you wanted to take this simple line graph

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~mpg, ~wt) %>% layer_lines()
```

with the y-variable `wt` given as a string like you are doing in your function, it would look like this:

```
curr = "wt"
mtcars %>% ggvis(~mpg, prop("y", as.name(curr))) %>%
    layer_lines()
```